# Control Panel won't log out, loops when logging back in randomly

Tags: control-panel, htaccess, caching

I upgraded to EE 2.7.3 a few months back and recently added caching preferences to our .htaccess file for site optimization. Since these changes, I'm currently having two issues:

- Sometimes when I press the 'Log-out' button, it just refreshes the
  page and keeps me logged in.
- After I'm logged out based on time or when the 'Log-out'
  button does work, when I try to log back in - I will occasionally
  have the screen loop on a white screen and it won't
  go to the control panel.

Clearing my cache solves both issues. I don't have a problem doing this, but we're starting to roll the control panel out to others at work and I would rather it just work.

In my 'Security and Session Preferences', I have the CP Session type set to 'Cookies and session ID'.

My .htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 hours"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

I didn't think this would affect the control panel itself, but I may be wrong.

Do I have to specify I don't want the control panel cached, or does this sound like an issue unrelated to the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a multi config environment? If you are, depending on how it's set up it may be looking for www.

I ran into this problem, (couldn't log in) but adding this to the .htaccess fixed it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the ExpiresDefault. Because it's a catch-all I believe it's setting bad expire headers on the cookies. I was having the same exact issue and removed only that line and all was well!